# Disable GitLab Confirmation-Email

Tags: gitlab

Recently I installed GitLab for my Company (a dockerized Container based on sameersbn/gitlab). When my users (authenticated with CAS) are trying to create their accounts they are getting email confirmation message. (which I do not have configured GitLab to send)

Now my question is I want to disable the email confirmation feature.

What file do I have to configure in the gitlab?
I don't want to change the users.rb file if possible.

Which options do I have to change this behaviour.

Comment: You mean this is not uncommented? https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/56a456b43dba7d772db45e2b73aa18b5eab53d37/config/gitlab.yml.example#L43

Comment: this is not the point. the point is if the admin creates a user account then this user account cannot do anything unless a valid email is provided to which gitlab can send a confirmation email (like: please klick this link to confirm your account). i want to skip the whole confirmation step and enable admin created users by default.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is really no option (searched the offical gitlab forum, github, etc) ended setting up the smtp settings, so gitlab can send those confirmation emails.